# https fails for java sdk for aws-s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I am using java sdks for was to connect to s3 over https protocol. O have the following.

```
ClientConfiguration clientconf = new ClientConfiguration();
      clientconf.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS);
      s3client = new AmazonS3Client(creds,clientconf);
      Logger.log("Getting bucket/key properties");
      bucket = props.getProperty("S3Repository.bucket");
      sequenceNumberKey = props.getProperty("S3Repository.sequenceNumberKey");
      Logger.log("Initialized s3 repository. bucket="+bucket+", sequenceNumberKey="+sequenceNumberKey);
   }
```

but I get the following error :

> [11 Jun 15:11:18 S3SequenceNumberManager]: [REMOVETHIS] s3repository :
>   com.netvention.apps.metadataadmin.repository.S3Repository@2a01dba5 [11
>   Jun 15:14:41 S3Repository]: Unable to execute HTTP request: connect
>   timed out
>   ***Error [11 Jun 15:14:41 S3SequenceNumberManager]: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to execute HTTP request: connect
>   timed out

It still tries to connect over http ? what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: for the s3client are you setting a region or an endpoint?

Comment: @Mircea This is what we're trying now:       s3client.setEndpoint("https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com");

Comment: by default the Protocol is https so you do not really need to specify, can you list all your buckets : `s3client.listBuckets();` also in your code what is `props` and how do you define it ?